# Different use of this operator in android

Tags: android, this

I want to know different use of this operator in android. I have seen some example, but I get confused like:

```
Intent intent=new intent(Main Activity.this, Second Activity.class)
```

here what "this" refer to?

```
Handler handler= new handler();

Thread t1;

t1=new thread(new runnable)){
    void run(){
        handler.postdelayed(this,2000);
    }
}
```

here, what "this" refer to?

I know that "this" refer to the current instance of the class, but here whose instance is passing thread class or any other and any more example anybody know regarding this keyword.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent function you using has take Context and Class as its parameters,

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

hence the `this` here is the Context. So in general, it you want to use the current class you working on as the Context as the parameter for some function, use `this`.
Read more about the Intent constructor [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))

In the second block of code, `this` refers to the Runnable class you want the function to run on.

I suggest you google about function or constructor to traceback what are the parameters.

Comment: will you please explain how it refer to runnable class and not thread class??

Comment: @tushar because the enclosing class is `Runnable` and not `Thread`. Notice that you're using `this` inside the `run()` method of `Runnable`.

Comment: because Handler.postDelayed() take Runnable as its parameter and also you're creating an anonymous Runnable class, hence `this` refers to that Runnable class

Comment: It cannot refer to `Thread` since it's not an enclosing class.

Comment: t1=new thread(new runnable)) means here runnable class is of anonymous type class

Comment: @tushar well, you're not naming it... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: but i have read that runnable is an interface used for thread creation, then how it can be a class in mentioned example.

Comment: because Interface or Abstract can also be considered as a class